# Scala getting a value from a map when unsure if the map holds the value

Tags: scala

In scala, I have a map.

I want to ask for an object - say a Train -  from my map. Then I want to call the, say, "getNumberOfCarriages" method on my Train.

If I don't know if the map has an entry for the key value "Thomas", how, in scala, do I safely query for the number of carriages, or return some default value (for the sake of the example, 0?)

ie how do i call

```
myMap.get("Thomas").getNumberOfCarriages()
```

I've seen a `getOrElse` method, but I am uncertain if it is applicable to the problem?

Comment: `myMap.get("Thomas").map(getNumberOfCarriages`) returns `Option[Int]`. It's up to you and your problem how to interpret. Stay with `Option` or get value with fallback to default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is `lift` it to an `Option` and then `fold` over it to get either the number of carriages or a default value if `None`.

```
myMap.lift("Thomas").fold(0)(_.getNumberOfCarriages())
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for. i'll accept when it lets me